# firebase-messaging - Fatal: failed to find callback

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM messaging and keep getting this error.

`E/FlutterFcmService( 3684): Fatal: failed to find callback`

Below is the code I've used to setup.

```
  static Future<void> messagePiper(
      Map<String, dynamic> message,
      FilteredMap<String, ChatMessage> globalChatEntryMap,
      FilteredMap<String, ChatMessage> gameChatEntryMap,
      Subject<List<ChatMessage>> globalChatSubject,
      Subject<List<ChatMessage>> gameChatSubject,
      Map<String, Player> _playerMap) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = message['data'];
    if (data.containsKey('name')) {
      final msg = ChatMessage.fromMap(data);
      globalChatEntryMap.putIfAbsent(msg.id, () => msg);
      globalChatSubject.add(globalChatEntryMap.values.toList());
    } else {
      final msg = GameChatMessage.fromMap(data);

      final chat = ChatMessage.fromGlobalChatMessage(
        msg,
        _playerMap[msg.pId].name,
        _playerMap[msg.pId].imageUrl,
      );

      print('chat: $chat');
      gameChatEntryMap.putIfAbsent(msg.id, () => chat);
      print('_gameChatEntryMap : $gameChatEntryMap');
      gameChatSubject.add(gameChatEntryMap.values.toList());
    }

    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

is the callback passed in to `FirebaseMessaging` configuration.

```
  final FirebaseMessaging _fm = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {

   _fm.configure(
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('onMessagee : $message');
          return Utils.messagePiper(
              message,
              _globalChatEntryMap,
              _gameChatEntryMap,
              _globalChatSubject,
              _gameChatSubject,
              _playerMap);
        },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('onLaunch : $message');
          return Utils.messagePiper(
              message,
              _globalChatEntryMap,
              _gameChatEntryMap,
              _globalChatSubject,
              _gameChatSubject,
              _playerMap);
          ;
        },
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          print('onResume : $message');
          return Utils.messagePiper(
              message,
              _globalChatEntryMap,
              _gameChatEntryMap,
              _globalChatSubject,
              _gameChatSubject,
              _playerMap);
          ;
        },
        onBackgroundMessage: null);
....
```

Java configuration file

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

dependency versions

```
  random_string: 0.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_database: ^3.0.7
  provider: 3.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  collection: ^1.14.11
  audioplayers: ^0.13.2
  firebase_admob: ^0.5.5
  connectivity: ^0.4.4
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6 # tried with several different versions
```

I tried with several `firebase_messaging` versions but couldn't find a fix.

Appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Comment: How come you have a custom Application class but no `onBackgroundMessage` callback? You only need the custom java file if you want to use background messaging.

Comment: Java file?


MainActivity.kt
importing it?

```
    import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
```

and put it?

```
    flutterEngine.plugins.add(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService())
```

in configureFlutterEngine?

Answer (score 31):

This error message is coming from `startBackgroundIsolate` which is used for allowing handling background messages.
If you don't want to handle background messages then you can safely ignore this error message. Otherwise, you need to set up a callback for handling background messages as described [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

If your callback is not executed when clicking on the notification then it's because you didn't set `click_action` property of the message to `FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK`

Comment: I am sending the ```click_action ```: ```FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK``` in the notification still getting an error in onMessage callback as: ``` Fatal: failed to find callback```

Comment: Me too
Android only

failed to find callback

Comment: @shinriyo as said you should ignore this "failed to find callback" error message if you do not intend to handle background messages. If you want to get rid of this error message then you need to setup a callback for handling background messages

Answer (score 4):

Are you sending FCM using the web, not FCM console?
make sure the post request is correct on your backend. I'm using Laravel

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization'=> 'key='. $token,
        ])->post($url, [
            'notification' => [
                'body' => $request->summary,
                'title' => $request->title,
                'image' => request()->getHttpHost().$path,
                
            ],
            'priority'=> 'high',
            'data' => [
                'click_action'=> 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                
                'status'=> 'done',
                
            ],
            'to' => '/topics/all'
        ]);
```

Comment: So it worked with just adding 'click_action' parameter to data.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare a backgroundMessageHandler function that is outside a class or as a static function, in order to be reached from outside, and then you pass this function to fbm.configure:

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print('on background $message');
}

fbm.configure(
      onMessage: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onLaunch: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onResume: (msg) {
        print(msg);
        return;
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
);
```

Also open your_project_folder/android/app/source/AndroidManifest.xml and paste this XML code after existing intent-filter code of your main Activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The result will be similar to the following code:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Application` class use the below code

previously it was `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);`,

replace it with
`FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));`

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry){
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to send a notification from the firebase console just to test my app receives notifications, I also encountered the same error. Make sure you kill the app on your emulator so it is not running in the background. And now try sending a notification from the firebase console, wait for a couple of seconds and you should see it. This worked for me.