# FlutterFcmService("number"): Fatal: failed to find callback

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using **firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16** package, and I did everything that was required of me, and after I sending the  firebase message, I got this error :

> FlutterFcmService(12133): Fatal: Failed to find callback

I searched for this issue but got nothing

I found one solution but it did not help me, [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58175367/10498374)

any help, thank you...

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: I use same the example code in the package, https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-, and I added the breakpoints in everywhere

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Me too. you resolve? no push notification...

Comment: Make sure that you listen to the notifications when starting the application.

Comment: I get notifications working, but I am also seeing random (infrequent) crashes that I think are related to this same function: " public static void startBackgroundIsolate(Context context, long callbackHandle)". Please share if you find any fix to this

Answer (score 3):

Following this answer helped me solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64483134/2931049

Please note the onBackgroundMessage part. Not implementing it as well as the others gave me the `Failed to find callback error`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);`
with

```
FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
```

Please check this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64781529/2082723)