# nothing happens upon receiving firebase cloud message on flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android app using flutter which uses Firebase cloud messaging.
Everything was working fine and it was receiving cloud messages but recently nothing happens when the device receives a cloud message no matter the app is in foreground or background or terminated.
The only thing that is logged into console is:

```
E/FlutterFcmService: Fatal: failed to find callback
```

which from what I know it belongs to the fact that I haven't handled background messages and despite this I should be able to receive the message.
how can I realize what is the cause of this problem? a log file or something?

PS:
I've tested on real devices with Android version 21 and 29 and the results are the same.

PS:
I've done

```
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter clean
```

and removed the app entirely then installed it again.

PS: I've sent the message using Firebase console and the project backend. both include 'notification' field inside the message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156832/firebase-messaging-fatal-failed-to-find-callback

Comment: @Merym yep, it didn't work. now I'm getting the notification when the app is background. but when I tap on notification, onResume is not called. And also when I'm inside app , onMessage function is not called

Comment: what eror do you get now

Comment: @Merym I'm getting the notification when the app is background and the notification is shown in notification bar. but when I tap on notification, onResume is not called. And also when I'm inside app , onMessage function is not called and I get:E/FlutterFcmService: Fatal: failed to find callback

Comment: you have to add click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'

Comment: @Merym I'm adding this bro. furthermore, click_action is used to trigger onResume and onLaunch when tapping notification.my problem is even when app is in foreground, onMessage is not called and it logs to console :Fatal: failed to find callback

Comment: you have to put youre code